# Getting all values from a list that do not have today's date in Python

Tags: python, database, list, datetime

I am connecting to a database and retrieving a list of cameras and their respective id's. Then, I traverse through this list and get the current time of these images that have last been captured. I want to find all the cameras and their respective id's that have not been captured on today's date *only* (2018-06-28).

```
import psycopg2
import os
import datetime

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='allow').cursor()

all_cameras_query = "SELECT cameraid, name, url, latitude, longitude FROM cameras ORDER BY cameraid"
conn.execute(all_cameras_query)
all_cameras = conn.fetchall()

current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

last_updated_list = []

for camera in all_cameras:
    last_updated_query = "SELECT cameraid, curr_time FROM images WHERE cameraid=%d ORDER BY curr_time DESC" % (
        camera[0])
    conn.execute(last_updated_query)
    last_updated_list.append(conn.fetchall())


print(last_updated_list)
```

last_updated_list prints out a list of every cameraid and the last captured time. Now, using python lists and searching, I would like to use the current_date to get all cameras that are *not* from today.

```
[(185, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 27))], [(186, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 27))], [(187, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 27))], [(188, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 27))], [(189, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 27))], [(190, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 27))], [(191, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 27))], [(192, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 28))], [(193, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 28))], [(194, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 28))], [(195, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 29))], [(196, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 29))], [(197, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 29))], [(198, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 29))], [(199, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 29))], [(200, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 29))], [(201, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 29))]]
```

I'm not too sure how to use this list and manipulate it to get these camera id's and the dates that I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define today's date as

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
```

Then loop through the list and save to a new list all items that aren't from today

```
new_list = [it for it in last_updated_list if it[0][1].date() != today]
```

In your example all the items are from today so as a result you get an empty list

```
print(new_list)
[]
```

Comment: I'm receiving a 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bad_cams.py", line 25, in <module>
    new_list = [it for it in last_updated_list if it[0][1].date() != today]
  File "bad_cams.py", line 25, in <listcomp>
    new_list = [it for it in last_updated_list if it[0][1].date() != today]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I used the list that you posted in your question as an example, which has the form `[[(no, date)], [(no, date)], ... ]` I suspect that `last_updated_list` might have different format. Can you please double check and post an update?

Comment: `last_updated_list` has the format `[[(no, date)]`:
ex: `[(193, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 10, 1, 28))]`

Comment: I think you are still missing something here in your description, the brackets do not really match. But please try replacing `it[0][1]` above with `it[1]`. I think this will do the trick.

Comment: This worked. The issue was the initial query which was storing empty tuples so it was giving the error.